# nodejs socket.io mysql missing error handler on socket reference

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sockets, express

I want to show log client json array.

**Server**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.emit('startsocket', 'welcome to timeserver');

    socket.on('timestart', function (data) {
        if (data == "start") {
            test();
        }
    });

    function test() {

        var ss = [];     
        var str = 'SELECT * FROM tb_realtime_data'       
        db.query(str, function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;

            rows.forEach(function (data) {


                ss.push(data);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(ss));
            });

        })

        socket.emit('testnow', ss);
        setTimeout(test, 1000);

    }

});
```

**Client**

```
var socket = io('http://127.0.0.1');


socket.on('startsocket', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('timestart', 'start');
});

socket.on('testnow', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

log server is Ok but log client does not work. help me Please.

It shows `array[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db.query is an asynchronous call which means that the last function your specified in the parameter will be called when the database result is fetched after the query executes.

```
db.query(str, function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    rows.forEach(function (data) {
      ss.push(data);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ss));
    });
})
```

You are sending the event on socket.io after registering callback so while the data is being fetched from the database, node sends the testnow event to the client and at that time your array is empty.

```
 socket.emit('testnow', ss);
```

You need to send the event after your results are received from the database so put the statement above in the callback function of db.query.

```
db.query(str, function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    socket.emit('testnow', JSON.stringify(rows));
})
```

To get more information on the asynchronous design pattern check out the [chapter](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html) in Mixu's Node Book.

EDIT
If you want to emit the data after all the rows are processed in the rows.forEach method, you can use a counter and then send the event to the server when the counter reaches total rows. SetTimeout would not ensure that all the rows are processed.

```
db.query(str, function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var ctr = 0
    rows.forEach(function (data) {
        ss.push(data);
        ctr++;
        // This will show your array on every forEach call
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ss));
        if (ctr === rows.length -1) {
            // This will emit the event only when all the forEach calls are completed
            socket.emit('testnow', ss);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: but i refresh page socket.io don's sent data

Comment: You need to send some event on the client side when the page refreshes to tell the server to fetch the list and send it back to the client on 'testnow' event.

Comment: thank you i part settimeout  out rows.forEach(function (data)

Comment: please checkout the edit. It might help you understand the async pattern.